# How to determine what makes up the "all conversions" metric

Tags: google-ads

Relatively new to google ads, and I have set up a campaign which is running and doing alright. I only have one goal right now, and that is `calls from ad`, which is getting conversions. I am noticing one of my ad groups is pulling in more `all conversions` with no other information attached.

Google has some light [documentation](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/3419678?hl=en) on this metric but I am not understanding how I can use the tools in Google Ads to reveal which and what conversions are happening. Google says a conversion can be many things such as Store visits or calls from mobile numbers, which is too vague to be useful.

I have tried segregated my Google Ads reports by several conversion metrics, devices, analytics information, but I am not seeing any clear indications on what google considers a conversion.

**Am I missing something easy on revealing what conversions google said have happened within my ad group?**

Answer (score 2):

At the top of the page, tap Tools and then select Conversions.  This will list all the conversions that are set up.  You can see in this table which are actually working, last conversion date, etc...

If you want to see which conversions are happening for which keywords, not just a total conversion count and cost, here's the way I've found:

In the tools menu, choose "Search attribution".  This has all sorts of info about the collected conversions.  Focus on the Paths button in the left menu, as you can drill down to the keyword level here, to find out which actual conversion types were triggered at the keyword level.

(If anyone knows how to get a custom column in the keywords list of a campaign or ad group to display a count of a particular type of conversion, please post an answer here...)

Also note: "all conversions" are simply all conversions *including* those of conversion types you had said shouldn't be counted as conversions in the conversion settings. I guess so you can segregate conversions into two categories (those you care about just sometimes, vs truly all conversions).